# Problems in parsing variable in email body (template) stored in database laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have an issue in parsing variable.

I have dynamic email template for send birthday wish

Suppose i want to send Bday email and i have email template message for bday stored in database.

In database it is stored a message  **Happy Birthday {{ $bday_user->name }}**

But when i sent email it is sending  **Happy Birthday {{ $bday_user->name }}** instead of actual name like **Happy Birthday Shiv**

```
Mail::send('mailTemplate.sendBdayWish',
  [
   'template_message' => $template_message ,
   'bday_user' => $bday_user 
  ], 
  function($message)use($mail_id,$bday_user) {  

 $message->to($mail_id, 'Shivshankar Shegaji')->subject('Happy Birthday '.$bday_user->name);

});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what error you're getting?

Comment: have you tried replacing 'Shivshankar Shegaji'?

Comment: when i sent email it is sending Happy Birthday {{ $bday_user->name }} instead of actual name like Happy Birthday Shiv on sendBdayWish view

Comment: what the name of the view ?

Comment: **sendBdayWish**

Comment: Is it save with proper extension as .blade.php?

Comment: yes its saved as .blade.php extension